# how to filter duplicates by the length of a property value

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I have an object array with duplicates. It is supposed to have duplicates but it needs to be limited to the number of months in one of the property values.

```js
const DATA = [
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Jan",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Feb",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Jan",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Feb",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Jan",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Feb",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "WAYZETTA 67-2536H",
    "entityId": 31135395,
    "selectedColumn": "Mar",
    "selectedColumns": "Mar"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Jan",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Feb",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Jan",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Feb",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Jan",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Feb",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Jan",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Feb",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Jan",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Feb",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Jan",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Feb",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Jan",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Feb",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Jan",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Feb",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Jan",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Feb",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Jan",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Feb",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  }
]

const DESIRED_RESULT = [
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Jan",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H",
    "entityId": 31340479,
    "selectedColumn": "Feb",
    "selectedColumns": "Jan Feb"
  },
  {
    "wellName": "WAYZETTA 67-2536H",
    "entityId": 31135395,
    "selectedColumn": "Mar",
    "selectedColumns": "Mar"
  }
]
```

I have given the Desired Result. Every wellName such as MARYS DRAW 461-2227H will have a property selectedColumns with a string of months. I need to limit the duplicates to the same amount of months and also each duplicate needs to have one of the 3 months set as the selectedColumn.

Comment: What specifically denotes a duplicate, and when one is encountered what should happen?  Take the first one?  Last one?  Does it matter?

Comment: doesnt matter at all

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?  What were the results?  Can we see the code?

Comment: So you want to make sure that no two objects in the output array have the same values for `selectedColumn` and `selectedColumns`?

Comment: ^^^ or is it enough to just check the entityId?  What specifically do you have to check against for "duplicate" to be true

Comment: Ive tried all kinds of things. There are other issues that is causing this but I need a quick fix. And what Ive tried isn't worth sharing

Comment: Please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Comment: @ShivashriganeshMahato no. the selectedColumn will contain only 1 of the months

Comment: I mean if you take two elements, `a` and `b`, `a.selectedColumn !== b.selectedColumn && a.selectedColumns !== b.selectedColumns`?

Comment: @ShivashriganeshMahato it's not as simple as that.  They want to allow duplicates, but only a reduced number.  I'm assuming they want the number to be equal to the number of months in the `selectedColumns` property.  So removing all duplicates isn't a solution, if I'm reading the question correctly

Comment: @ShivashriganeshMahato the selectedColumns will stay the same. Im sorry if wasn't clear enough. If Marys has Jan, Feb, Mar in selected columns. then I need 3 copies of Marys with the only thing being unique is the selectedColumn.

Comment: @Taplar yes that is correct. I find know how to phrase it correctly

Comment: So there should be a number of elements that share the same value for `selectedColumns` equal to the number of months in that value, and each element should have a different value for `selectedColumn`?

Comment: @ShivashriganeshMahato yes that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for:

```
let result = [];
let filter = {};
let col, cols;

// Iterate through every element
data.forEach(datum => {
  col = datum.selectedColumn;
  cols = datum.selectedColumns;
  // Add selectedColumns value if not already tracked
  if (!filter[cols]) {
    filter[cols] = [];
  }
  // Make sure element with same selectedColumn value doesn't already exist
  if (filter[cols].indexOf(col) === -1) {
    filter[cols].push(col);
    result.push(datum);
  }
})
```

Basically what it's doing is keeping track of the found selectedColumns values, then mapping each to an array storing selectedColumn values and making sure they aren't duplicated in the result.

Comment: If this is correct, then the `entityId`/`wellName` fields don't matter at all.  But in the comments above, there was a mention of `MARY`, which makes me suspect that this would fail on different data, if say we appended another entity (say `JOSEPHS DRAW`) with `Jan Feb` /  `Jan`.  That would be excluded as a duplicate of the first one.  I don't think this is desired.

Comment: Very true, would that be an issue @texas697?

Comment: My answer solves it differently by generating a key from the data.  It's not always possible, but when it works, I find it simpler than using this sort of manual checking.

Comment: @ScottSauyet you are correct. I did run into that problem. however I was able to fix the source of the problem and no longer needed a quick work around

Answer (score 1):

One way I solve such problems is to temporarily fold my list into an object with keys made up of important parts of the object, and values (in this case) being the existing result if there is one there or the current one.  This is just a `reduce`  Then I just take the values of this object, ignoring the keys, using `Object .values`.

Here is one approach:

```js
const dedupe = data => Object .values (data .reduce ((
  a, entry, _, __, 
  key = `${entry .entityId} | ${entry .selectedColumn} | ${entry .selectedColumns}`
) => ({...a, [key]: a [key] || entry}), {}))

const DATA = [{wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Jan", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Feb", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Jan", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Feb", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Jan", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Feb", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "WAYZETTA 67-2536H", entityId: 31135395, selectedColumn: "Mar", selectedColumns: "Mar"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Jan", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Feb", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Jan", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Feb", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Jan", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Feb", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Jan", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Feb", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Jan", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Feb", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Jan", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Feb", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Jan", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Feb", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Jan", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Feb", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Jan", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Feb", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Jan", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}, {wellName: "MARYS DRAW 461-2227H", entityId: 31340479, selectedColumn: "Feb", selectedColumns: "Jan Feb"}];

console .log (dedupe (DATA))
```

From the data, I'm making the assumption that we need to match only on `entityId`, that `wellName` and `entityId` are always correlated.  If that's false, it's easy enough to add the well name to the key.

The only slightly tricky bit about this code is assigning the `key` inside the parameters to `reduce`.  I like this approach as it makes my function body a single expression.  But here, in a `reduce` callback, it's a little awkward because of the third and fourth arguments (index and array) that `reduce` supplies you.  I just ignore them by supplying the unused parameters `_` and `__`.  But those could be `i`, and `arr` or anything else just as well.